# GPUImage: Tried to overrelease a framebuffer, did you forget to call -useNextFrameForImageCapture before using -imageFromCurrentFramebuffer?

Tags: ios, iphone, gpuimage

I keep getting this error on and off. I've seen some solutions that recommend using the GPUImageNormalBlendFilter in the filter chain however doing so has resulted in a solid grey colored output.

```
videoCamera = [[GPUImageVideoCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720 cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionFront];
filter = [[GPUImageFilter alloc] init];

[videoCamera addTarget:_filter];
blendFilter = [[GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter alloc] init];
blendFilter.mix = 1.0;

animatedImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
[contentView addSubview:_animatedImageView];
[contentView addSubview:[self watermark]];
uiElementInput = [[GPUImageUIElement alloc] initWithView:contentView];

[filter addTarget:blendFilter];

[uiElementInput addTarget:blendFilter];

[blendFilter addTarget:filteredVideoView];
```

filtered video view is GPUImageView

Answer (score 1):

You must use setFrameProcessingCompletionBlock and invoke uiElement's update method:

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
[filter setFrameProcessingCompletionBlock:^(GPUImageOutput *filter, CMTime frameTime) {
    [weakSelf.uiElementInput update];
}];

[videoCamera startCameraCapture];
```